# C# download file from dropbox and convert it to HttpPostedFile

Tags: c#, post, dropbox, httppostedfile

My web site has an option to upload files from local computers.
I want to now add an option to upload files straight from dropbox.
I am using the dropbox chooser api which returns the link for the file chosen by the client.

I then want to download the file to the server and convert it to `HttpPostedFile` 
or post it again as a `HttpPostedFile` - because my functions expect a `HttpPostedFile` object...

Can somebody help me find a way to do that?

idan.

Comment: You should change your function to accept `HttpPostedFileBase` (which you can inherit from) or your own wrapper class.

Comment: i didn't understand how to use HttpPostedFileBase with the file i get from dropbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your own class that inherits `HttpPostedFileBase` and implements its methods using the Dropbox API.

You can then pass that class for files from Dropbox, and `HttpPostFileWrapper` for regular uploads.

If you're using ASP.Net MVC, you will get `HttpPostedFileBase` directly for regular uploads, and you can create a custom model binder to automatically handle Dropbox too.